# How can I create a counter for a nested list in the Racket language?

Tags: list, nested, racket, counter, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a counter in Dr Racket that will go through a nested list and output the count.

[I currently have this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK91V.jpg)      (I left all the 3s in the list)

It is currently outputting 3 (these are the first three 3s)
I'm assuming it's getting to the end of that first nested list and stops at that point, but I can't seem to figure out what to do. (Yes, this is an assignment, but it's our second assignment in racket, and over spring break as well. It's due the day we go back)

```
    (define (genCounter lst target c)
      (cond
         ((empty? lst) c)
         ((list? (first lst))
          (genCounter (first lst) target c))
         ((eq? (first lst) target)
          (genCounter (rest lst) target (+ c 1)))
         (else
          (genCounter (rest lst) target c))))
```

I'm not expecting you to provide me with the answer, but just explain what should be changed or teach me more about the language than my professor did.

So I changed the list used to (genCounter '(3 (3 3 (3 3 3)) 3 (3 (3))) 3 0) and it returned 6 (which I tested to find it was the first 6 being returned. I believe that when it comes to the end of one of the lists, it stops going through the function, but like I said, I don't know exactly what to implement in order to fix it (although I know what's wrong with it).

Here's what I ended up creating:

```
     (define (genCounter lst target)
      (if (null? lst) 0
          (let ((current (first lst)))
            (cond
              ((list? current)
               (+ (genCounter current target) (genCounter (rest lst) target)))
              ((eq? current target)
               (+ 1 (genCounter (rest lst) target)))
              (else
               (genCounter (rest lst) target))))))
```

Comment: post your code not image of code.

Comment: I have updated it to include the actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got a working solution now I'll show you

**an alternative to your working code**

```scm
(define (genCounter lst target)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (+ (genCounter (rest lst) target) 
         (let ((x (first lst)))
           (if (list? x)
               (genCounter x target) 
               (if (eqv? x target) 1 0))))))
```

Note that

- There's less redundancy in the code, at the expense of adding `0` when the first element doesn't match
- You should not use `eq?` for numbers, but rather `=` or `eqv?`; have a look at `equal?` also

**code that works with an accumulator (like in your first version)**

```scm
(define (genCounter lst target)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (count 0))
    (if (empty? lst)
        count
        (loop (rest lst)
              (let ((x (first lst)))
                (if (list? x)
                    (loop x count)
                    (if (eqv? x target) (add1 count) count)))))))
```

Of interest:

- I moved the accumulator `count` to an internal procedure (a named let in this case), it should not be part of the main procedure's signature
- All the magic happens in the recursive call to `loop` at the end, including an *additional* recursive call if the first element is a list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's not name an identifier as `list`. `list` is a function that constructs a list. If you use this name, you are shadowing it and thus will not be able to use it in the function! Below, I will use `lst` instead.

Now, for your question, the answer is, your second branch is wrong:

```
[(list? (first lst)) (genCounter (first lst) val c)]
```

What this does is: "if the first element is a list, dive into this sublist, count things, and then answer".

Can you see why it's wrong?

Suppose you want to count 2 in the following list:

```
(list (list 2 2 2) 2 (list 2 (list 2)))
```

Because the first element, `(list 2 2 2)`, is a list, it dives into this sublist and count 2. The answer is 3. However, the expected output is 6!

The problem is, you don't want to count 2 only in the first element, you want to count 2 in

```
(list ... >>> 2 (list 2 (list 2)) <<<)
```

as well.

That is, you want to count 2 in the rest of the list, after counting 2 in the first element, and then sum them up.

Comment: I see what you're saying (that it ends after the first sub-list) but I'm not really seeing how I fix it. I need to run through the rest of the list at some point, but I don't quite know how or at what point to implement it. Should I be setting up some statement where, at the end of the first element of the list, it goes onto the "rest"?

Comment: When you encounter an element that is a list, then your overall result is the count of that sublist + the count of the rest of your initial list.